# Document ready error

Tags: jquery, document, ready

I'm trying to run this code, but it breaks my entire page. The page is marked up like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#right_column h1").each( function() {  
   var link = $(this).html()+"<br />";
   document.write(link); 
});
});
</script>
<div id="right_column">
<h1>Company Profile</h1>
blablablablabla<br />

<h1>Nulla turpis nunc, dapibus ultricies.</h1>
blablablabla<br />
<h1>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique proin laoreet.</h1>
blablablabla<br />
```

When i try to run the code, it only shows me the content of the 3 h1's, the rest of the page (the h1 themselves) aren't loaded anymore. When i remove the $(document).ready() function, and put the script block after everything, it works just fine.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`!  That's the problem.  It's erasing your entire page!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `document.write` after the document is read.

If you want to append to the page, do this :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#right_column h1").each( function() {  
       var link = $(this).html()+"<br />";
       $(document.body).append($(link));   
     });
   });
```

Comment: Changing it to this worked->
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#right_column h1").each( function() {  
       var link = $(this).html()+"<br />";
       $("#location_where_i_wanted_them_to_show").append(link);   
     });
   });

The $(link) should be just link

Answer (score 0):

I will use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#right_column h1").each( function() {  
   var link = $(this).html()+"<br />";
   $("#container-element").html('<a href="' + link + '">TEXT-YOU-WANT</a>');
});
});
</script>
```